# Why PRESENT is a dummy value in map.put(e,PRESENT) in add method in HashSet?

Tags: java

When we call

```
HashSet set = new HashSet();
set.add(1);
```

the `add` method will internally call the `put` method of map with value
`map.put(1,PRESENT);`.

Why is `PRESENT` passed as a dummy value in `map.put`?

Comment: A map needs a value.

Comment: Unrelated: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: I appreciate the accept ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a conceptual point, a Map represents a superset of a Set: it contains all the keys of a Set.

Thus, it is very well possible to implement a Set by re-using a Map. But of course a Map needs a key **plus** a value.

So: when you decide to implement a Set by re-using a Map, adding a key to the set results in adding a key plus a dummy value to that map. And it is useful to use a non-null value, so that you can later decide whether removing a specific key actually removed anything.

Comment: Same as for removing, you also get information when _adding_ about whether there was already a value there (without having to do `containsKey` first).  `map.put(e, PRESENT)` will be `null` if not previously added (and so for a `Set`, the `add` succeeded), or `PRESENT` if it was previously added (and so the `add` failed).

Comment: Additionally, I assume using `key` would be a bad idea whenever someone chose to add a `null` element to the `HashSet`, falling into the same pitfalls already mentioned when using `null`.

Comment: @GhostCat I understood that it should be non-null value but why PRESENT is passed over there, keyword could be anything instead of PRESENT.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the implementation of `HashSet`, a `Map` is used to remember which values the set contains. Or, to put it in other words, which value is *present*.

So in order to store the `Set`'s values, each value is put into the `Map` as a key. Since the value behind the key does not matter, a dummy value is used. That dummy value is very simple and small in order to minimize memory footprint:

```
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object(); //from HashSet's sourcecode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the instantiation of a `HashSet` :

```
public HashSet() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

It's represented as a `hashmap`, the values you add to the set are added as `keys` to the map with dummy object values, that's how `HashSet` avoids duplications